# Taking a value from a UITextField, calculating another value, and updating a UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, calculator

I am working on a simple calculator app. I have my "text box" for input, and a label for output, both placed in a view controller.

I would like to take the input from the text box as an integer, do some mathematical calculations such as multiplication, and then output to the text label.

How can I do a simple calculation like this?

With this code, I get an error on the line `var mDeposit = enterMoneyAmount - deposit`:

> Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UITextField' and 'Int'

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    let fee = 1.20
    let tax = 1.07
    let deposit = 100


    @IBOutlet weak var moneyResults: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var enterMoneyAmount: UITextField!

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    var mDeposit = enterMoneyAmount - deposit    // Error here
    var mDepositAndFee = mDeposit * fee
    var mDepositAndFeeAndTax = mDepositAndFee * tax


        mDepositAndFeeAndTax.text = moneyResults

     }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I think you'll have better luck here asking more specific questions than "how to make an app that does X". Try something, write some code, if it doesn't work, post a question here (with the code attached). As it it, your question is too broad, and will probably be closed as such. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the text for UItextLabel equal to the value you get after calculation on button press.

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
     endingCash = ((startingCash * fee) + (endingCash * tax) + (endingCash + deposit))
     moneyResults.text = endingCash
}
```

Comment: I did as you suggested but I'm getting the error above

Comment: @JoshuaAbrams This is because you are subtracting A UITextField with a int value. You will need to parse UITextField to Int and then this will work. 

    **var mDeposit =  Int(enterMoneyAmount.text) - deposit**

Let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because you are currently trying to subtract an `Int` from a `UITextField`. You need to grab the text from the enterMoneyAmount text field, and convert that `String?` to an `Int`, or handle the case where there is an input error. For example:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    guard let moneyAmountString = enterMoneyAmount.text,
        let moneyAmountInt = Int(moneyAmountString)
        else {
        //either moneyAmountString or moneyAmountInt is nil
        //handle that input error here
        return
    }

    //enterMoneyAmountInt is now a valid Int
    var mDeposit = enterMoneyAmountInt - deposit

    /*the rest of your code here */
}
```

This is the swift 3 syntax. If writing for below swift 3, remove the second 'let' in the guard statement.

Comment: Won't that crash on a broken outlet `enterMoneyAmount` since it's defined using the force-unwrap operator?

Comment: yes, it would, but it's not common practice to unwrap IBOutlets since they are force-unwrapped by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can't treat a UITextField as an Int (or a Double, or any type of number.)

UITextFields have a property text that holds a value of type String.

You need to extract the string value and convert it to an int:

```
@IBOutlet weak var moneyResultsLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var enterAmountField: UITextField!

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let enteredAmountString = enterAmountField?.text ?? ""
    let enteredAmount: Double = Double(enteredAmountString) ?? 0
    var mDeposit = enteredAmount - deposit
    var mDepositAndFee = mDeposit * fee
    var mDepositAndFeeAndTax = mDepositAndFee * tax
    moneyResultsLabel.text = String(mDepositAndFeeAndTax)
}
```

I renamed your outlets to make it clear what they are. (Text fields and labels.) Using a name like `enterMoneyAmount` makes you think that variable holds and amount, and does not point to a text field that collects input from the user.

I also wrote my code to convert the input value to a floating-point type so the user could enter amounts in dollars and cents. (or amounts in any currency with decimals.)

The line

```
let enteredAmount: Double = Double(enteredAmountString) ?? 0
```

Uses `??`, which is the "nil coalescing operator". It says "If the expression on the left is not nil, leave it alone. If it is nil, replace it with the expression on the right. So if `enteredAmountString` can't be converted to a Double (because it contains "xyz", for example.) then `Double(enteredAmountString)` will evaluate to nil. In that case, it gets replaced with zero.

Comment: Thank you that did the trick i had to convert my other variables to Doubles to make it work but it's working now, much appreciated!